# How to add content header to Flurl

Tags: rest, httpclient, flurl

I would like to know how to add a content header to a flurl-statement.
The onedrive implementation requires me to add a content-type header to the content, and tried every possible solution with no luck.

I'm forced to use the regular httpclient with the following code.

```
Public Async Function UploadFile(folder As String, filepath As String) As Task(Of Boolean) Implements ICloud.UploadFile
        Dim data As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(filepath)
        Dim uploadurl As String = "drive/items/" + folder + ":/" + Path.GetFileName(filepath) + ":/" + "content?access_token=" + Token.access_token


        Using client As New HttpClient()
            client.BaseAddress = New Uri(ApiUrl)

            Dim request As HttpRequestMessage = New HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, uploadurl)

            request.Content = New ByteArrayContent(data)
            request.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream")
            request.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Length", data.Length)

            Dim response = Await client.SendAsync(request)

            Return response.IsSuccessStatusCode
        End Using
    End Function
```

I already tried the regular PutJsonAsync method of Flurl, but with no luck.
It's the only non-flurl piece remaining in my code.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real issue here is that there's currently no out-of-the-box support for sending streams or byte arrays in Flurl. I plan to add some soon, but with the implementation details you already have it's easy to add this yourself with an extension method. (Forgive the C#, hopefully you can translate to VB.)

```
public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PutFileAsync(this FlurlClient client, string filepath) 
{
    var data = File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
    var content = new ByteArrayContent(data);
    content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
    content.Headers.Add("Content-Length", data.Length);
    return client.SendAsync(HttpMethod.Put, content: content);
}
```

The above works if you already have a `FlurlClient`, but as the [docs](https://flurl.dev/docs/extensibility) describe it's a good idea to have corresponding `string` and `Url` extensions, which can just delegate to the above method:

```
public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PutFileAsync(this Url url, string filepath)
{
    return new FlurlClient(url).PutFileAsync(filepath);
}

public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PutFileAsync(this string url, string filepath)
{
    return new FlurlClient(url).PutFileAsync(filepath);
}
```

Tuck those away in a static helper class and they should work seamlessly with Flurl:

```
await uploadurl.PutFileAsync(filepath)
```

Comment: Thank you Todd, i'll give that a try.